# Concatenate more than 2 dataframes side by side using a for loop

Tags: pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I am new to Pandas and was curious to know if I can merge more than 2 dataframes (generated within a for loop) side by side?

Comment: `pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `pandas` library's `DataFrame` method called `concat`.

Here's documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

(Avoid looping over dataframes at all costs. It's much slower than the tools provided to you by pandas. In most cases, there's probably a pandas function for it, or a few you can use together to achieve the same thing.)